# Java 8 streams maps with parameters

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have this couple of functions and I would like to know if it is possible to pass the parameter `deviceEvent.hasAlarm()` to `.map(this::sendSMS)`

```
private void processAlarm (DeviceEvent deviceEvent)  {

        notificationsWithGuardians.stream()
                    .filter (notification -> notification.getLevels().contains(deviceEvent.getDeviceMessage().getLevel()))
                    .map(this::sendSMS)
                    .map(this::sendEmail);

    }

    private DeviceAlarmNotification sendSMS (DeviceAlarmNotification notification, DeviceEvent deviceEvent)  {

        if (deviceEvent.hasAlarm()) {       

        }

        return notification;

    }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use a lambda instead of the method reference.

```
// ...
.map(n -> sendSMS(n, deviceEvent))
// ...
```

Answer (score 6):

> ... I would like to know if it is possible to pass the parameter `deviceEvent.hasAlarm()` to `this::sendSMS`

No, is not possible. When using method reference you can pass only one argument ([docs](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html)).

But from the code you provided there is no need for such thing. Why to check `deviceEvent` for every notification when it is not changing?
Better way:

```
if(deviceEvent.hasAlarm()) {
  notificationsWithGuardians.stream().filter( ...
}
```

Anyway, if you really want, this can be a solution:

```
notificationsWithGuardians.stream()
                .filter (notification -> notification.getLevels().contains(deviceEvent.getDeviceMessage().getLevel()))
                .map(notification -> Pair.of(notification, deviceEvent))
                .peek(this::sendSMS)
                .forEach(this::sendEmail);

 private void sendSMS(Pair<DeviceAlarmNotification, DeviceEvent> pair)  { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a Class or Member vaiable and assigning value to it and reusing in the reference method provided if reference method is in same class